# Remove item from a list in c++

Tags: c++, list

I have this program where I want to insert and delete items in a list. I'm having trouble with my remove function. I want the user to tell me which index they want to delete in the list and then decrease the size of the list and then move the items together. 
For example: 333 222 111
if I delete the 2nd number then the list would look like
 333 111 
and the size of the list would decrease to 2.

thanks in advance!

```
/*  insert
 *  parameters:
 *    index  -- the place in the list to insert newItem
 *    newItem -- the item to insert into the list
 *  returns:
 *    true -- if the item is successfully inserted
 *    false -- otherwise
 *  precondition:  0 < index
 *  postcondition:  newItem is in postiion "index" of the list
 *  Algorithm:  stuff
 */

bool myList::insert(int index, ListItemType newItem) {
    if (!(index > 0)) {
        cerr << "insert:  precondition failed with index = " << index << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (size == MAX_LIST) {
        cout << "List is full" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (index > size) {
        items[size] = newItem;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    //list is not full and index is b/w items 1 and size-1
    for (int i = size; i >= index; i--) {
        items[i] = items[i - 1];

    }

    items[index - 1] = newItem;
    size++;

    return true;
}

bool myList::remove(int index) {
    //I tried this but it doesn't work well enough
    if (!(index > 0)) {
        cerr << "insert:  precondition failed with index = " << index << endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--) {
        items[index] = items[index + 1];

    }

    size--;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise, prefer `std::list<>`.

Comment: no, `std::vector<>`

Comment: the problem lies in your `for` loop.  For each item after the target deletion index, you need to move it back one position.  You have all the information, but the loop logic is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, what @BenjaminLindley said.

Comment: You should consider using "unsigned int" or indeed size_t as your inputs for indicies rather than int. It'll absolve you of the "<0" checks. I agree with @Benjamin though.

Comment: @CraigWright: That will simply result in undefined behavior if he *does* pass in a negative number.  unsigned ints are stupid.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Conversion from signed to unsigned is well defined and required to yield the value modulo appropriate generator (maximal value + 1). And all calculations in unsigned type are again done modulo this generator. On the other hand signed calculations are done as if in whole numbers and the behaviour is undefined if the result can't be represented. There is no undefined behaviour for unsigned types.

Comment: @JanHudec: Neat, but irrelevant to what I said.  If he takes out the "<0" checks, as Craig suggested, it *will* result in undefined behavior when he passes in negative numbers, unless his containers are extremely large, or he passes in extremely large negative numbers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: No. If he used unsigned type for the index, negative number would add to the end, because too large numbers are explicitly handled in the code and negative number would just be a too large number.

Comment: @Benjamin The unsigned int gives a very clear signal to the caller that no negative numbers are accepted. It's a better interface because it communicates design intent. It's also inline with the STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other people said, you should try to use stl. But going with the code you have so far. You should change your *for* for something like this:

```
for (int i = index; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    items[i] = items[i+1];

}
```

What this does is, from the deleted item on, replace each item with the one that follows. It is like shifting to the left.

This wont destroy any elements, but I am guessing we can let that go.

Comment: It works, & what do you mean by "destroy any elements"? @Nick & thanks!

Comment: It means that you loose a handle to them before deleting them. But that depends on how you create them. If newItem is not a pointer don't worry about that, they will be deleted automatically.